# Makefile to compile from a specific toolchain

Tags: c++, makefile, toolchain

I have receive a makefile from another source. I am supposed to cross-compile on my machine (x86_64, GCC 5.3) it to use on an arm-embedded device (host). I tried to compile with a tool chain (arm_64, GCC7.5) which i installed in my /opt directory by making the following changes (those that are remarked out #) in the makefile of the project

```
#SYSROOT?=$(shell $(CXX) --print-sysroot)     
SYSROOT= /opt/yocto/sysroots/
CXXFLAGS= -std=c++11 -I  src/  
CCFLAGS= -std=c++11 -I src/  
#CXX_LDFLAGS= -L /usr/local/aarch64-linux/lib/ -lpthread -pthread 
CXX_LDFLAGS= -L $(SYSROOT)/aarch64-yocto-linux/lib -lpthread -pthread 

all: foo
   
foo: src/foo.cpp 
    $(CXX) -std=c++11 -g -o $@ $^ $(CXX_LDFLAGS)

clean:
    rm -rf .objs
```

However when the code was compiled, it could not be run on host device(arm) and there was warning during make that say along lines of skipping incompatible binaries.

I perform file on the compiled application. It read

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=99376bcc919a48224e063ec6c6892e1979b5d94e, not stripped
```

It is clear to me that I have compiled it with my native compiler,libraries etc.

What should i do in this case:

1. must i do the following before compilation or making the folder

   ./configure -build xxxxx -host yyyyyy
2. there is some files, called environment files (full of export settings) in the tool chain directory that seems to be like some configuration settings being exported. Should i use this file? or how should i use them

Regards

Comment: As you didn't assign your cross-compiler command name to `CXX`, make use the default, that is, a compiler for your PC (x86-64).

Comment: @RenaudPacalet: How should I do that ,...may i ask

Comment: @RenaudPacalet:  I have managed to solve the problem by source <environment-setup-file-toolchain> followed by export LD=